# can i manage ubuntu users or multiple pcs by using windows xp..?

Tags: 12.04

actually i have 10 ubuntu pcs and i want to centralize management all of them via windows xp. All pcs are connected using wi-fi. I have problem with command line interface so i want to manage all of them by windows XP. please give me a permanent solution.

Comment: If the solution you want is based of Windows XP this is off topic. We supply solutions and offer opinions for Ubuntu related questions.

Comment: Permanent solution? With Windows XP? For how long are you planning to run it?

Comment: You may want to look at Remmina or something similar. It might be able to help you temporarily (until you will learn how to use Ubuntu).